# Avoid blurring on a child item when hovering a blurred div element / Bootstrap5.2

Tags: css, filter, hover, bootstrap-5, card

Pls I would need help to avoid having a blur effect on my child element "text-block" when the mouse is hovering the card element. The card element should completely have a blur effect when hovering with the mouse & display the text block over it.

I tried a lot of options that don't work throught the proposed solutions by the community. Thks a lot.

```
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <div class="container my-2">
            <a href="/Zanzibar.html"><img src="./images/mnemba_view.JPG" class="w-100 w-sm-120 preview"/></a>
            <div class="text-block">Click to read more</div>
          </div>  `
```

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  block-size: 50px;
  inline-size: 200px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(189, 113, 20);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card:hover .text-block{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card:not(hover) .text-block {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.card:hover {
  filter: blur(2px);
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution.

Here's the solution:

```css
  .text-block {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    block-size: 50px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    inline-size: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(189, 113, 20);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="album py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header fw-bold" style="background-color:#b76800a9">Africa</div>
                <div class="preview">
                  <a href="/Zanzibar.html"><img src="./images/mnemba_view.JPG" alt="Ile de Mnemba" class="w-100 h-sm-200 w-sm-120 align-item-center justify-content-center"/></a>
                  <button class="text-block">Click to read more</button>
                </div>
```